# HuggingFace Model Dockerization

Tags: docker, huggingface-transformers

I built an application which uses Flask, Gunicorn with Hugging Face Model of size 850 Mb.

And when I am trying to create and run the application as a Docker container, unfortunately, due to the size of the model, the docker fails to download and keeps downloading in a loop.

It takes quite some time and when the application gets an API request,  it says **Booting worker with pid** and the download starts again.

The same model works fine without docker, with no issues in downloading the models.

How can I optimize the process?

This is what my Docker file looks like:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:5000", "wsgi:app", "--workers=1"]
```

My Application code is as follows:

```
model_happy_tt = None
args = None

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    # with app.app_context():
    global model_happy_tt, args
    model_happy_tt = HappyTextToText("T5", "vennify/t5-base-grammar-correction")
    args = TTSettings(num_beams=5, min_length=1)
    model_happy_tt.generate_text("grammar: " + "It's a jst run!!", args=args)
    return app


app = create_app()

@app.route('/')
def welcome() -> str:
    return f'Welcome to ProofReader Service'


@app.route('/proofread', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def proofread() -> str:
    global model_happy_tt, args
    text = request.args.get('text')
    result = model_happy_tt.generate_text("grammar: " + text, args=args)
    return jsonify({'corrected_text': result.text})
```

And wsgi file is as follows:

```
from app.proofreaderapp import app,create_app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # app.run()
    create_app.run()
```

Alternatively, I tried to download and package the model while building the Docker Image, and the size of the image along with the model is quite huge 2+GB and it is not an optimal solution for me. Without a model file, the image size is 50 Mb hardly.

I am not sure how to optimize the docker run process to download and save the model after the container starts running.

Any suggestion would be really helpful.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  It would be helpful if you could [edit] the question to include a [mcve]: if this doesn't work in Docker, what is in your `Dockerfile` and how are you starting the container?

Comment: @DavidMaze Yeah added all the info to reproduce the issue

Comment: Since you don't want to include the model inside the container, how about you put it into a volume?  Also, the model weights take only 900 MB, maybe you saved it twice since transformers will cache it automatically.

Comment: What is a volume?

Comment: You basically mount a directory from your host system into the container.  [More info](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

Comment: I need to explore more on this. Thanks for the info.